# How do I enable Firestarter to run at Ubuntu startup

Tags: firestarter

Firestarter does not appear to have an option to enable it to run at Ubuntu startup. Is their a specific setting in Ubuntu that I need to edit to enable this?

Comment: Bill, Firestarter is no longer supported. This likely presents security issues among other things, so you shouldn't use it. For a graphical firewall similar to Firestarter, try "GUFW" which is a wrapper for UFW.

Answer (score 1):

The linux firewall is actually a feature of the kernel, and firestarter/etc are essentially just graphical configuration tools. So as long as firestarter is saving its configuration, those rules should be enabled on boot.
http://www.fs-security.com/docs/faq.php#reboot

However, you are probably asking about getting a system tray icon, which is covered by the firestarter FAQ:
http://www.fs-security.com/docs/faq.php#trayicon